# ReactNative.createClass is deprecated use React.createClass from "React" package instead

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Anyone knows why this warning is heading up ?

another warning is : ReactNative.createElement is deprecated. Use React.createElement from "react" package instead.

Code is :

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
Text,
View,
StyleSheet,
} = React;

module.exports = React.createClass({
render: function(){
return(
  <View>
    <Text>{this.props.titleName}</Text>
  </View>
);
}
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{

},
text:{

}
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Importing React from react-native has been [deprecated in 0.25.1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.1). It will stop working in 0.26.

You should do this now:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
```

**Edit**: If you still get deprecation warnings after fixing your code, you are probably using dependencies that have not yet been updated. To fix these warnings do the following:

1. Check if there are updates available that fix the imports.
2. Use [this script](https://github.com/sibeliusseraphini/codemod-RN24-to-RN25) to rewrite your dependencies to use the correct imports automatically. It will take quite some time and rewrite some files that have nothing to do with react. `jscodeshift -t transform.js PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT/node_modules/`
3. To find the remaining files that require React from react-native you can set a breakpoint in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/ReactNative.js at line 41 that is where the warning is triggered.

When you find a dependency that has not been updated it's probably a good idea to submit an issue or if you have the time a PR.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. How do we find the source of the error when we've double checked React is being imported from 'react'? Could it be in one of my countless node_modules? Unfortunately the debugging tools aren't more specific.

Comment: Yes, it's probably in one of your dependencies. The best method I have found so far is to set a breakpoint in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/ReactNative.js at line 41 where the warning is triggered.

Comment: FYI, the codemod linked to in #2 now supports a variety if import styles including destructuring elsewhere.